# Why MongoDB skip() doesn't use indexes?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, performance, query-optimization

It's stated in MongoDB's documentation that using skip() with big offsets is slow.

> The skip() method requires the server to scan from the beginning of the input results set before beginning to return results. As the offset increases, skip() will become slower.

Assuming that there's an index on the field that we sorted by, why can't MongoDB just "jump" right to the right place? e.g. If we had a sorted array, we could get the 100th item in O(1). Why can't databases do the same?

As far as I understand the exact same thing happens with OFFSET/LIMIT in SQL databases, so I will highly appreciate an answer that covers both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are not stored on disk/in memory as arrays. They are stored as trees which are somewhat like linked lists.

For this reason, it is impossible to '"jump" right to the right place', as you say.

Note that the documentation doesn't say that the server iterates the *documents* but that iterates the *result set*. That could be done via an index scan, in theory.

Comment: Thank you, I think that I understand how it works now.